# Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'

Tags: r, performance, sorting, r-caret

I am running the code in order to fit a LASSO analysis but when I run the code I get the following error: `Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'`. Could someone shed more light on the problem?

```
library(caret)
set.seed(3523)
library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)
data(concrete)
inTrain = createDataPartition(concrete$CompressiveStrength, p = 3/4)[[1]]
training = concrete[ inTrain,]
testing = concrete[-inTrain,]

library(lars)
lasso <- lars(x=as.matrix(as.factor(training), 
   y=concrete$CompressiveStrength,     type="lasso", trace=FALSE,
              normalize = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess last command in your code should look like this:

```
lasso <- lars(x=as.matrix(training), y=training$CompressiveStrength,     type="lasso", trace=FALSE,normalize = TRUE)
```

Comment: cool! Then please accept this answer and upvote  if you want.