# different caret/train erros when using oob and k-fold x-val with random forest

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

Here is the code I'm using:

```
# data set for debugging in RStudio
data("imports85")
input<-imports85

# settings
set.seed(1)
dependent <- make.names("make")
training.share <- 0.75
impute <- "yes"
type <- "class" # either "class" or "regr" from SF doc prop


# split off rows w/o label and then split into test/train using stratified sampling
input.labelled <- input[complete.cases(input[,dependent]),]
train.index <- createDataPartition(input.labelled[,dependent], p=training.share, list=FALSE)
rf.train <- input.labelled[train.index,]
rf.test <- input.labelled[-train.index,]

# create cleaned train data set w/ or w/o imputation
if (impute=="no") {
    rf.train.clean <- rf.train[complete.cases(rf.train),] #drop cases w/ missing variables
} else if (impute=="yes") {
    rf.train.clean <- rfImpute(rf.train[,dependent] ~ .,rf.train)[,-1] #impute missing variables and remove added duplicate of dependent column
}

# define variables Y and dependent x
Y <- rf.train.clean[, names(rf.train.clean) == dependent]
x <- rf.train.clean[, names(rf.train.clean) != dependent]

# upsample minorty classes (classification only)
if (type=="class") {
    rf.train.upsampled <- upSample(x=x, y=Y)
}

# train and tune RF model
cntrl<-trainControl(method = "oob", number=5, p=0.9, sampling = "up", search='grid') # oob error to tune model
tunegrid <- expand.grid(.mtry = (1:5)) #create tunegrid with 5 values from 1:5 for mtry to tunning model
rf <- train(x, Y, method="rf", metric="Accuracy", trControl=cntrl, tuneGrid=tunegrid)
```

The 1st error is kind of related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33453618/error-in-sort-listy-x-must-be-atomic-for-sort-list) but using `caret` and `randomForest` instead of `lars` and I don't get it...
*Error in order(x[, 1]) : 'x' must be an atomic vector for 'sort.list' - did you call 'sort' on a list?*
And no, I did not call 'sort' on a list... at least not that I'm aware of ;-)

I checked the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/4.47/topics/train) for `caret` / `train` and it says that x should be a dataframe which is the case according to `str(x)`.

If I used k-fold x-validation instead of oob error like so

```
cntrl<-trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number=5, repeats = 2, p=0.9, sampling = "up", search='grid')
```

There is another funny error:
*Can't have empty classes in y*

Checking `complete.cases(Y)` seems to indicate there are no empty classes though...

Does anyone have a hint for me?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of your dependent variable. You chose `make`. Did you inspect this field? You have training and testing; where do you put an outcome with only one observation, like `make = "mercury"`? How can you train with that? How could you test for it if you didn't train for it?

```
input %>% 
  group_by(make) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  arrange(count) %>% 
  print(n = 22)

# # A tibble: 22 × 2
#    make        count
#    <fct>       <int>
#  1 mercury         1
#  2 renault         2
#  3 alfa-romero     3
#  4 chevrolet       3
#  5 jaguar          3
#  6 isuzu           4
#  7 porsche         5
#  8 saab            6
#  9 audi            7
# 10 plymouth        7
# 11 bmw             8
# 12 mercedes-benz   8
# 13 dodge           9
# 14 peugot         11
# 15 volvo          11
# 16 subaru         12
# 17 volkswagen     12
# 18 honda          13
# 19 mitsubishi     13
# 20 mazda          17
# 21 nissan         18
# 22 toyota         32
```

You also had warnings when you executed the function `createDataPartition()`. I think the `randomForest` package requires a minimum of five per group. You can filter for the groups you'll include and use that data for testing and training.

Before the comment labeled `settings` you can add the following to subset the groups and validate the results.

```
filtGrps <- input %>% 
  group_by(make) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  filter(count >=5) %>% 
  select(make) %>% 
  unlist()

# filter for groups with sufficient observations for package
input <- input %>% 
  filter(make %in% filtGrps) %>% 
  droplevels() # then drop the empty levels

# check to see if it filtered as expected
input %>% 
  group_by(make) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  arrange(-count) %>% 
  print(n = 16)
```

This only uses 5, which isn't ideal. (More would be better.)

However, all of your code works with this filter.

```
rf
# Random Forest 
# 
# 147 samples
#  25 predictor
#  16 classes: 'audi', 'bmw', 'dodge', 'honda', 'mazda', 'mercedes-benz', 'mitsubishi', 'nissan', 'peugot', 'plymouth', 'porsche', 'saab', 'subaru', 'toyota', 'volkswagen', 'volvo' 
# 
# No pre-processing
# Addtional sampling using up-sampling
# 
# Resampling results across tuning parameters:
# 
#   mtry  Accuracy   Kappa    
#   1     0.9505208  0.9472222
#   2     0.9869792  0.9861111
#   3     0.9869792  0.9861111
#   4     0.9895833  0.9888889
#   5     0.9921875  0.9916667
# 
# Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
# The final value used for the model was mtry = 5. 
rf$finalModel
# 
# Call:
#  randomForest(x = x, y = y, mtry = min(param$mtry, ncol(x))) 
#                Type of random forest: classification
#                      Number of trees: 500
# No. of variables tried at each split: 5
# 
#         OOB estimate of  error rate: 0.52%
# Confusion matrix:
#               audi bmw dodge honda mazda mercedes-benz mitsubishi nissan peugot
# audi            24   0     0     0     0             0          0      0      0
# bmw              0  24     0     0     0             0          0      0      0
# dodge            0   0    24     0     0             0          0      0      0
# honda            0   0     0    24     0             0          0      0      0
# mazda            0   0     0     0    24             0          0      0      0
# mercedes-benz    0   0     0     0     0            24          0      0      0
# mitsubishi       0   0     0     0     0             0         24      0      0
# nissan           0   0     0     0     0             0          0     24      0
# peugot           0   0     0     0     0             0          0      0     24
# plymouth         0   0     0     0     0             0          0      0      0
# porsche          0   0     0     0     0             0          0      0      0
# saab             0   0     0     0     0             0          0      0      0
# subaru           0   0     0     0     0             0          0      0      0
# toyota           0   0     0     0     0             0          0      1      0
# volkswagen       0   0     0     0     0             0          0      0      0
# volvo            0   0     0     0     0             0          0      0      0
#               plymouth porsche saab subaru toyota volkswagen volvo class.error
# audi                 0       0    0      0      0          0     0  0.00000000
# bmw                  0       0    0      0      0          0     0  0.00000000
# dodge                0       0    0      0      0          0     0  0.00000000
# honda                0       0    0      0      0          0     0  0.00000000
# mazda                0       0    0      0      0          0     0  0.00000000
# mercedes-benz        0       0    0      0      0          0     0  0.00000000
# mitsubishi           0       0    0      0      0          0     0  0.00000000
# nissan               0       0    0      0      0          0     0  0.00000000
# peugot               0       0    0      0      0          0     0  0.00000000
# plymouth            24       0    0      0      0          0     0  0.00000000
# porsche              0      24    0      0      0          0     0  0.00000000
# saab                 0       0   24      0      0          0     0  0.00000000
# subaru               0       0    0     24      0          0     0  0.00000000
# toyota               0       0    0      0     22          0     1  0.08333333
# volkswagen           0       0    0      0      0         24     0  0.00000000
# volvo                0       0    0      0      0          0    24  0.00000000
```

Of course, you'll still want to test this model.

Comment: Thanks so much! I had try to do two steps at once (set up the randomForest and tune it via train) and was not able to understand the propagation of the error. When I did the randomForest only I thought I had found another issue which turns out to be the same and which you have solved with this as well (just in case you want to take credit, don't know how to add you there): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70682890/stratified-sampling-using-createdatapartition-drops-small-classes-out-of-test

Comment: Thank you @ MarkH!

Comment: It's been a while and only now do I get around to pick up the work on this project...

What you wrote totally makes sense but when I really put that piece of code into the original one I'm still getting the original error. How did you get this to run?

Difficult in comments so I'll add the code updated as per your suggestion as another answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
library(randomForest)
library(caret)
library(dplyr)

remove(list=ls())

# data set for debugging in RStudio
data("imports85")
input<-imports85

filtGrps <- input %>% 
  group_by(make) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  filter(count >=5) %>% 
  select(make) %>% 
  unlist()

# filter for groups with sufficient observations for package
input <- input %>% 
  filter(make %in% filtGrps) %>% 
  droplevels() # then drop the empty levels

# check to see if it filtered as expected
input %>% 
  group_by(make) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  arrange(-count) %>% 
  print(n = 16)

# settings
set.seed(1)
dependent <- make.names("make")
training.share <- 0.75
impute <- "yes"
type <- "class" # either "class" or "regr" from SF doc prop


# split off rows w/o label and then split into test/train using stratified sampling
input.labelled <- input[complete.cases(input[,dependent]),]
train.index <- createDataPartition(input.labelled[,dependent], p=training.share, list=FALSE)
rf.train <- input.labelled[train.index,]
rf.test <- input.labelled[-train.index,]

# create cleaned train data set w/ or w/o imputation
if (impute=="no") {
    rf.train.clean <- rf.train[complete.cases(rf.train),] #drop cases w/ missing variables
} else if (impute=="yes") {
    rf.train.clean <- rfImpute(rf.train[,dependent] ~ .,rf.train)[,-1] #impute missing variables and remove added duplicate of dependent column
}

# define variables Y and dependent x
Y <- rf.train.clean[, names(rf.train.clean) == dependent]
x <- rf.train.clean[, names(rf.train.clean) != dependent]

# upsample minorty classes (classification only)
if (type=="class") {
    rf.train.upsampled <- upSample(x=x, y=Y)
}

# train and tune RF model
cntrl<-trainControl(method = "oob", number=5, p=0.9, sampling = "up", search='grid') # oob error to tune model
tunegrid <- expand.grid(.mtry = (1:5)) #create tunegrid with 5 values from 1:5 for mtry to tunning model
rf <- train(x, Y, method="rf", metric="Accuracy", trControl=cntrl, tuneGrid=tunegrid)
```

Comment: You've got the code I provided and some of your original code- how did you get `input.labelled`? Did you recreate it after the code I provided? Or are you still inadvertently using the old data?

Comment: I have (or at least I think I have) used my original code and just added yours. Your code filters `input` in place, right? And after that there is the original line of code which removes all rows which have no label:
`input.labelled <- input[complete.cases(input[,dependent]),]`

Comment: Wow, yes, you are right. (sheesh, I can't believe I missed that!) I copied the code in this answer as is, with no additional libraries called. It worked. So let's look at versions: randomForest 4.7-1, caret 6.0-91, lattice 0.20-45, dplyr 1.0.8, ggplot2 3.3.5, intel Mac, R version 4.1.1 (Kick Things), what do you have?

Comment: Thanks for being so dedicated to my little problem!
randomForest 4.6-14 vs. your 4.7-1,
caret 6.0-86 vs. yours 6.0-91,
lattice 0.2-41vs. yours 0.2-45,
dplyr 1.0.2 vs. yours 1.0.8,
ggplot2 3.3.2 vs. yours 3.3.5,
WIN10 vs. your Mac and
TERR 6.0.0 vs. your open source R 4.1.1
The last one got me thinking so I got myself an open source R4.1.2 but with the exact same package versions I had in TERR. And, surprise, it works. So there is something wrong with TIBCO's version of R and I will open up a support ticket at their end.
Thanks so much, would never have figred this out alone!

Comment: Great! I'm glad you've got it worked out.