# Stratified sampling using createDataPartition drops small classes out of test

Tags: r, sampling

I'm trying to do stratified sampling, and I realized that when I have classes with very few cases, I can end up with a test data set that has not a single case of these minority classes.

Here is some example code

```
library(caret)

# data set for debugging in RStudio
data("imports85")
input<-imports85
    
# settings
set.seed(1)
dependent <- make.names("make")
training.share <- 0.75
impute <- "no"
type <- "classification"

# save original column names for later and make R-friendly column names
original.names <- names(input)
names(input) <- make.names(original.names)
    
# create train and test data sets
input.labelled <- input[complete.cases(input[,dependent]),] #split off rows w/o dependent
if (impute=="no") { 
    input.clean <- input.labelled[complete.cases(input.labelled),] #drop cases w/ missing variables
} else if (impute=="yes") {
    input.clean <- rfImpute(input.labelled[,dependent] ~ .,input.labelled)[,-1] #or impute missing variables and remove added duplicate of dependent column
}

train.index <- createDataPartition(input.clean[,dependent], p=training.share, list=FALSE) #create row index for train data set using stratified sampling but very small classes might all go into train?!
rf.train <- input.clean[train.index,] #create train data set
rf.test <- input.clean[-train.index,] #create test data set from left-overs
if (type=="classification") { #balance train data set for classification (can be skipped if upsampling takes place as part of tuning settings cntrl)
    rf.train <- upSample(x=rf.train[, names(rf.train) != dependent], y=rf.train[, names(rf.train) == dependent], yname=dependent)
}

# define variables Y and dependent x
Y.train <- rf.train[, names(rf.train) == dependent]
x.train <- rf.train[, names(rf.train) != dependent]
Y.test <- rf.test[, names(rf.test) == dependent]
x.test <- rf.test[, names(rf.test) != dependent]

# train single RF model
rf <- randomForest(x.train, y=Y.train, xtest=x.test, ytest=Y.test, type=type, keep.forest=TRUE)
```

You will get a warning from `createDataPartition`, and you will see that e.g., "make"==chevrolet has 3 cases in rf.train and none in rf.test, which can cause issues downstream with the `randomForest`.

Any smart way how to avoid that w/o leaking data from the train into the test?

Comment: Turns out that the above issue is actually the underlying issue to this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70666227/different-caret-train-erros-when-using-oob-and-k-fold-x-val-with-random-forest
So @Kat has already a provided a solution there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of this is the same, but not all.

#### The same:

This is because of your dependent variable. You chose `make`. Did you inspect this field? You have training and testing; where do you put an outcome with only one observation, like `make = "mercury"`? How can you train with that? How could you test for it if you didn't train for it?

```
input %>% 
  group_by(make) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  arrange(count) %>% 
  print(n = 22)

# # A tibble: 22 × 2
#    make        count
#    <fct>       <int>
#  1 mercury         1
#  2 renault         2
#  3 alfa-romero     3
#  4 chevrolet       3
#  5 jaguar          3
#  6 isuzu           4
#  7 porsche         5
#  8 saab            6
#  9 audi            7
# 10 plymouth        7
# 11 bmw             8
# 12 mercedes-benz   8
# 13 dodge           9
# 14 peugot         11
# 15 volvo          11
# 16 subaru         12
# 17 volkswagen     12
# 18 honda          13
# 19 mitsubishi     13
# 20 mazda          17
# 21 nissan         18
# 22 toyota         32
```

When you executed the function `createDataPartition(), you also had warnings`. I think the `randomForest` package requires a minimum of five per group. You can filter for the groups you'll include and use that data for testing and training.

Before the comment labeled `settings`, you can add the following to subset the groups and validate the results.

```
filtGrps <- input %>% 
  group_by(make) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  filter(count >=5) %>% 
  select(make) %>% 
  unlist()

# filter for groups with sufficient observations for package
input <- input %>% 
  filter(make %in% filtGrps) %>% 
  droplevels() # then drop the empty levels

# check to see if it filtered as expected
input %>% 
  group_by(make) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  arrange(-count) %>% 
  print(n = 16)
```

This only uses 5, which isn't ideal. (More would be better.)

#### Change here

In the `caret` model, you used imputation. You didn't do that for this model. You dropped another 34 observations when you created `input.clean`. At that point...

```
# you removed another 34 rows- need to check the classes, again
# you imputed for caret/train
input.clean %>% 
  group_by(make) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  arrange(-count) %>% 
  print(n = 16)
# # A tibble: 16 × 2
#    make          count
#    <fct>         <int>
#  1 toyota           31
#  2 nissan           18
#  3 honda            13
#  4 subaru           12
#  5 mazda            11
#  6 volvo            11
#  7 mitsubishi       10
#  8 dodge             8
#  9 volkswagen        8
# 10 peugot            7
# 11 plymouth          6
# 12 saab              6
# 13 mercedes-benz     5
# 14 audi              4
# 15 bmw               4
# 16 porsche           1
```

You need to drop three more classes now.

```
# there is an exclamation point to negate this
input.clean <- input.clean %>% 
  filter(!make %in% c("audi", "bmw", "porsche")) %>% 
  droplevels()

# validate changes
input.clean %>% 
  group_by(make) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  arrange(-count) %>% 
  print(n = 16)
# 13 classes now
```

From here on, your code is good to go.

```
rf
# 
# Call:
#  randomForest(x = x.train, y = Y.train, xtest = x.test, ytest = Y.test,      keep.forest = TRUE, type = type) 
#                Type of random forest: classification
#                      Number of trees: 500
# No. of variables tried at each split: 5
# 
#         OOB estimate of  error rate: 1.92%
# Confusion matrix:
#               dodge honda mazda mercedes-benz mitsubishi nissan peugot
# dodge            24     0     0             0          0      0      0
# honda             0    22     0             0          2      0      0
# mazda             0     0    24             0          0      0      0
# mercedes-benz     0     0     0            24          0      0      0
# mitsubishi        0     0     0             0         23      0      0
# nissan            0     0     0             0          0     23      0
# peugot            0     0     0             0          0      0     24
# plymouth          0     0     0             0          0      0      0
# saab              0     0     0             0          0      0      0
# subaru            0     0     0             0          0      0      0
# toyota            0     0     0             0          0      1      0
# volkswagen        0     0     0             0          0      0      0
# volvo             0     0     0             0          0      0      0
#               plymouth saab subaru toyota volkswagen volvo class.error
# dodge                0    0      0      0          0     0  0.00000000
# honda                0    0      0      0          0     0  0.08333333
# mazda                0    0      0      0          0     0  0.00000000
# mercedes-benz        0    0      0      0          0     0  0.00000000
# mitsubishi           1    0      0      0          0     0  0.04166667
# nissan               0    0      0      1          0     0  0.04166667
# peugot               0    0      0      0          0     0  0.00000000
# plymouth            24    0      0      0          0     0  0.00000000
# saab                 0   24      0      0          0     0  0.00000000
# subaru               0    0     24      0          0     0  0.00000000
# toyota               0    0      0     22          0     1  0.08333333
# volkswagen           0    0      0      0         24     0  0.00000000
# volvo                0    0      0      0          0    24  0.00000000
#                 Test set error rate: 3.23%
```

Just a tip- if you have these calls in the same script file, use unique object names between the models, that way, you always know what data is in which object. It can be a hidden error that causes all sorts of issues.